# JSNI method in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

Until I had this situation, it works :

**JS side:**

```
jsMethod : function(){...}
```

**GWT Java side:**

```
public static native void javaMethod(JavaScriptObject obj)  /*-{
    var test = null;
    test = ... ;
    test.jsMethod();    
}-*/;
```

The problem is when I try to do something like this

**JS side**

```
jsMethod : function(a, b){... return string}
```

**GWT Java side**

```
String a = 'yes'
String b = 'no'

public static native void javaMethod(JavaScriptObject obj)  /*-{
    var test = null;
    test = ... ;

    var testString = null;
    testString = test.jsMethod(a, b);   
}-*/;
```

I would be to pass parameter from GWT to JS and then returns a String but I dont' know how to make it. Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameters to the native JavaMethod

```
public static native String javaMethod(JavaScriptObject obj, String a, String b)  /*-{
    var test = null;
    test = ... ;

    var testString = null;
    testString = test.jsMethod(a, b);
    return testString;
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Java. Return a String.

```
public static native String javaMethod(JavaScriptObject obj)  /*-{
    var test = null;
    test = ... ;

    var testString = null;
    testString = test.jsMethod(a, b); 
    return testString;  
}-*/;
```

Comment: Okay, but I don't know how to pass parameters, is it required this: '[instance-expr.]@class-name::method-name(param-signature)(arguments)' ?